# How to get redirected to a welcome page with a passed username prop using Inertia.js in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I'm working on an Application with Laravel, vue.js (Inertia). There is a login page when the user enters the credentials, and if he is authenticated, he should be redirected to the "Welcome.vue," and I want to pass the username with it.

I have a login component that is accessible at "http://127.0.0.1:8000/Login" When the user fills out the form and hits the "login" now button following controller code is executed (which is working fine).

**This is my controller code**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $username =Auth::user();
        return Inertia('Welcome', [
            'username' => $username
          ]);
    } else {
        return back()->with('message','Authenticaiton Failed');
    }
}
```

Now I can receive it as a propos. But the problem with this method is that the page **URL remain the same** which is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/Login"

**I want to change it to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/Welcome".**

I can use the return `redirect('Welcome')->with('username',$username);` but I can't receive it as a prop. I don't know what's the exact issue.

**Following is the additional code that you might need:**

**Route Welcome**

```
Route::get('/Welcome', function () {
    return inertia('Welcome');
    
})->name('Welcome')->middleware('auth', 'AuthenticateCustom');
```

**Route Login**

```
Route::get('/Login', function () {
    return inertia('Login');
})->name('Login');

Route::post('/Login', [UserController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
```

Any leads or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for you to pass the username of the authenticated user and just redirect to the `Welcome` page. The `HandleInertiaRequest` middleware will handle that for you. If you want to access the authenticated user information you can just use the `usePage()`

**Inside `<script setup>` tag**

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const username = computed(() => {
    usePage().props.auth.user.username
})
</script>
```

**Inside the `<template>` tag**

```
<template>
    <span>{{ $page.props.auth.user.username }}</span>
<template>
```